# How to gotoAndPlay on mouseover in Adobe Flash AS 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In Adobe Flash CC As 3.0 I try to make add gotoAndPlay function on mouseover inside a scene.

I put this code:

```
this.stop();
this.addChild(overBtn);
this.overBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event)
{
        this.gotoAndPlay(17);    
});
```

But its not working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for adding an event listener is

```
<target>.addEventListener(<Event>,<function>);
```

**example**

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOver);
```

Then you'd have a function elsewhere like this:

```
private function mouseOver(me:MouseEvent):void{
    goToAndPlay(17);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for accessing handled object, inside event listener do this

```
this.stop();
this.addChild(overBtn);
overBtn.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event)
{
        event.target.gotoAndPlay(17);
});
```